# Subtract rows of imputed data frames from original data.frames

Tags: r, data.table, imputation

I've got a bit of a weird scenario, but am kind of stumped on the best/most efficient way of going about doing this.

I have 1000 samples with 100 rows generated from some simulated data. I have stored these samples in a single data.table object with a "dataset" column which reflects which 1 of the 1000 samples that data is from and an "id" column which is a unique value given to that row before generating the samples.

For each of these samples, I've performed some imputation on them which produces 10 imputed values for each original sample. This returns 1000 data.table objects where each data.table object is 1000 rows (10  rows per unique "id"). I have a ".imp" column in each of these data.table objects that range from 1 to 10 to reflect which imputation run that value was produced by.

I am looking to calculate the absolute difference between these imputed data.table objects and the sample. I wanted to store these differences in a final data.table object that records the "id" and the dataset number from the imputation (so 10 rows of the absolute difference per id value) with the absolute difference between them.

I was thinking I could do something like extract the rows from both the original and the imputed data for each id value, turn both into a data.table object, then just subtract the rows. I feel that this would be extremely inefficient.

Does anyone have any ideas about a more computationally efficient/less error prone way to do this?

Comment: I think you'll be a lot more likely to get actionable assistance if you can make this reproducible with code, perhaps reducing your *"1000 samples with 100 rows"* down to (say) *"5 samples with 3 rows"* or similar. Keep it small and there's a good chance somebody will dive into it. I think most tend to not work as hard on "word problems", for whatever reason.